# C# program open Word Application but not specific Word Document

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, docx

The code below is supposed to open a .docx file in my windows directory but instead of opening the file it opens only the Word Application. There is no active word document inside, not even a new document. I notice that under the file tab options like "save, save as, print, Share, Export, and Close" are all grayed out and inactive.

```
using Microsoft.Office;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void openFile()
    {
        string myText = @"‪C:\CSharp\WordDocs\MyDoc.docx";
        var wordApp = new Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        wordApp.Activate();

        Word.Documents book = wordApp.Documents;
        Word.Document docOpens = book.Open(myText);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello World\n");
        openFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran the code and it opens my file just fine.

Comment: Does the last line in your `openFile()` function throw an exception? I tried a path that doesn't exist for `myText`, in that case it does open an empty Word application with no document inside but it does throw an exception at the mentioned line.

Comment: The file path is probably wrong.

Comment: No exceptions. File path definitely correct and document exist. Problem persists when I move the file to any other directory. Even when I change the pathname to something nonexistent - it still opens the Word Application without errors, just like before.

Comment: I also looked at the version of microsoft office object library i am referencing in c# - it is 15.0. The the object library file in the office directory on my pc is also 15.0. I suspected it may be a compatibility issue with my Word but from my inspection it does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code but with a path that doesn't exist does indeed opens Word Application with no document inside. But it does throw a very informative exception as follows:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Sorry, we couldn't find
>   your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted? 
>   (C:\Users\nonexistantuser...\Test.docx)'

You failed to mention this in your question, but you must get an exception.

So my guess is your path is incorrect.

If the path is correct, i.e. the file exists, another possible scenario is not having appropriate read permissions. In that case again it would open an empty Word Application, but that too should throw an exception albeit a different one:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Word cannot open the document:  user does not have access privileges
>    (C:\Users\NS799\Desktop\Test.docx)'

So please check if the path exists and if it does, if you have appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

here I'm created the WPF button event to launch the word Application Hope this will help you . please check this out

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Windows;
namespace Word_Automation_WPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wd = newMicrosoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document doc;
private void btn_LaunchWord(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            wd.Visible = true;
            wd.Activate();
            wd = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
            doc = wd.Documents.Add();
        }
    }
}
```